# authentication for ownership of an ip address

Tags: networking, ip, ip-address

I'm new to networking, sorry if my question sounds dumb.
Let's say I purchase an ip address from an Internet domain registrar, do I get a password for authentication and who provides this authentication services? because ip address is public, someone else could claim this ip address is theirs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strictly speaking you can't purchase an IP address. The minimum number of IPs you can "purchase" is 256, and you would need to jump through massive hoops with a regional internet registry.

What you are likely doing is using an IP address from an ISP, which is part of a block they have acquired. There are no passwords associated with IP addresses.

What limits the ability for someone else to use yours is (a) The ISP control/advertising of the IP addresses, and how they assign them to devices. There is no single answer to how this is done - it could be associated with a PPP account (which does have a password) or a port on an exchange which goes to your house, or a MAC address....

Its important to realize that IP addresses are routed in blocks between peers that have some level if trust. If someone does abuse the trust the IP address can be misdirected (this has happened even at the level of "all IP addresses for a country" - although the claim to ownership still lies with the member who was assigned them from the RIR. (RIR's are regional registries who, between them ultimately handle ownership and assignations of IP space and routing numbers called AS numbers used between providers to route IP addresses using BGP)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. and let 's say I launch a start-up company and purchase/lease an ip address from the isp. After a while, I move my start-up company to another city for e.g lower state tax , does it mean that the ip address I purchased is not longer valid any more, and I have to purchase/ lease a new ip address form the ISP again?

Comment: because I read sth from a book: "It is the inclusion of the network identifier in the IP address of each host on the network that
causes the IP addresses to be network-specific. If you move a device from one network to a different one the network ID must change to that of the new network. Therefore, the IP address must change as well."

Comment: If you move to a different ISP, you will have  to purchase your service from the new ISP and then they will assign you a new IP or set of IP addresses.

Comment: @amjad - its a lot more complex, and a lot less relevant then that. You should not build your infrastructure arround an external IP address, you should usually use rfc1918 space, and have the static being in 1 location on the router, and refererred to by a domain name.

Comment: As far as moving a static between areas, thats entirely down to your ISP and their setup. Sometimes you can, sometimes you can't. Its highly unlikely you can move it between ISPs though. Also, if you locate your servers in DC's or in the cloud you can move offices but not servers.

Comment: None of this is to say "you don't need static IPs". They are useful for access control and hosting - its just that any setup should be such that a planned change of a static IP address should not be a big deal.

Answer (score 1):

Your Registrar registers your domain name. It is not connected to an IP address at all.

Your ISP supplies you with an internet connection with 1, 6, or more IP addresses. There is no password associated with these IP addresses.

You use the ISP for your own stuff, OR, your webmaster makes a Web Page using the domain you purchased above. You can run a Web service from this ISP or another one suited to running Web services.

Also IP addresses are assigned and no passwords are assigned to IP addresses.

There is a lot more to web services than the wee bit above but nonetheless that is the general core of what you are asking.